# In what order should I perform Fisher's r-to-z transformation and correction for range restriction and measurement error on correlation coefficients?

Tags: r, data-transformation, meta-analysis, measurement-error, fisher-transform

I have a two part question; both parts relate to correcting/transforming raw correlation coefficients for the purpose of a meta-analysis.

### Confirming my understanding of `correct_r` output

The documentation for `correct_r` discusses correcting for measurement error as wells as "true-score" correlations. I want to make sure I am properly understanding the documentation (in terms of which corrections have been performed on which output values). For my analysis, I would like to correct my correlations both for attenuation as well as for restriction of range.

Is a correlation (rxyi) corrected for measurement error in both X and Y the same as a "true-score" correlation? Practically speaking, I am wondering if `correct_R` output object `rtpa`, which is defined as the "range-corrected true-score correlation" is the equivalent of a correlation on which correction for disattenuation AND range restriction has been performed. It appears this way to me from the formulas in the documentation. Do readers agree?

### Correct, then r-to-z transform, or r-to-z transform, then correct?

For the purposes of my meta-analysis, I plan to meta-analyze correlation coefficients after performing a Fisher's r-to-z transformation. My question is whether I should transform, and then correct for measurement error/range restriction, or correct, and then transform.

I tried both ways and compared outputs: they produce different values. I would guess it is appropriate to correct, and then transform. I would appreciate any guidance on this topic. I would also appreciate hearing if you disagree with my plan to both correct and transform the coefficients.